# Move window controls in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, window

I am so done accidentally closing windows >_<
Can you tell me any way to move all three buttons a bit to the left, 5-10 pixels would do. Just to prevent accidental click of the X.
Unfortunately all info I can get out of Google is related to moving controls to **far** left, like in OS X or Ubuntu's Unity

Answer (score 1):

- Mess a little with your **mouse sensitivity**, might solve the problem
- **Change windows skin**: right click on desktop - personalise - try a windows 7 classic skin
- **Try other 3rd party skins**, here's an app i used a while ago: [Windowblinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/)
  , dont overdo it tho, might affect your performance.